# Can't use XMLDocument - "incomplete type is not allowed"

Tags: c++, tinyxml2

I am trying to parse XML content.
I want to use `XMLDocument` but when I use it like that:

```
XMLDocument doc;
```

I receive an error:

> incomplete type is not allowed

When I searched for this issue I found that some [places](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa335917(v=vs.71).aspx) write examples with these libraries:

```
#using <mscorlib.dll>
#using <System.dll>
#using <System.Xml.dll>

using namespace System;
using namespace System::IO;
using namespace System::Xml;
using namespace System::Xml::Schema;
```

But when I tried this I am received an error:

> #using requires C++/CLI mode

What I need to do in order to be able to use `XMLDocument` object ?

Comment: C++/Cli is a specific type of project. I use tinyxml v2 available on GitHub instead for c++. See https://github.com/leethomason/tinyxml2

Comment: What header declares `XMLDocument`?

Comment: XMLDocument is a .Net class for use in C# etc. I guess that is why it has to be in a C++/CLI project as managed code. That is why I used a simple library.

Comment: @Andrew Truckle I download tinyxml v2, compiled it as `.lib` file and added it's fullpath to the linker: Project Properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies. I follow the `xmltext.cpp` and tried to load XML content and in one of the example they are using: `XMLDocument doc;` and when I tried it, I receive the error from my question.

Comment: Theirs is in a namespace tinyxml2::XMLDocument. So you got to use the namespace. Else you add a “using tinyxml2” to it.

Comment: @DBedrenko It is declared in tinyxml: https://github.com/leethomason/tinyxml2/blob/master/tinyxml2.h#L1650

Comment: @E235 so `#include tinyxml2.h` and link against that library, and reference that class with `tinyxml2::XMLDocument`

Comment: @E235: Your problem might be that the name `XMLDocument` is rather generic. If you mean tinyxml2's `XMLDocument`, you must include "tinyxml2" in your web search, or you'll get irrelevant and misleading results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look in the example source file `xmltest.cpp` you will see at the top:

```
using namespace tinyxml2;
```

So when you see code like:

```
int example_1()
{
    XMLDocument doc;
    doc.LoadFile( "resources/dream.xml" );

    return doc.ErrorID();
}
```

It is actually:

```
int example_1()
{
    tinyxml2::XMLDocument doc;
    doc.LoadFile( "resources/dream.xml" );

    return doc.ErrorID();
}
```

You must use the `tinyxml2` namespace to identify the correct `XMLDocument` to use.

---

- When you add the source files to the project, right-click the `cpp` file and choose **properties**:

[image: Properties]

- Next, you need to tell it not to use **precompiled headers**:

[image: Not use precompiled headers]

Now you do not need the `#include stdafx.h` call.

---

As you can see, [XMLDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument(v=vs.110).aspx) is also a Microsoft .NET Framework class:

[image: .NET Framework XMLDocument]

Without the `tinyxml2` namespace it will default to this **.NET Framework** class. That requires a compatible application which, for **C++**, would mean a **C++/CLI project**.

Comment: I added `tinyxml2.h` and `tinyxml2.cpp` to my project like you wrote. Is there something else I need to do ? it looks it accept it but now I have different compile errors.

Comment: As I have stated, you can't just add the files to the project. You must use the `tinyxml2::` prefix to your function call. You do not need any of those other included headers / namespaces you referred to in your question. Take that code out.

Comment: OK, now it works. I also needed to add `#include "stdafx.h"` to `tinyxml2.cpp`. Thanks.

Comment: No, you do not need to do that. Please see updated answer.

Comment: Nice ! Thank you very much for your explanations.